# Seen logic for Social site function

Tags: mysql

I'm making a social site and I'm just confused with my logic for my seen function. Here is my `seen` table:

```
|seen_ID|seen_notif_ID|seen_viewers|
+-------+-------------+------------+
|   1   |    1200     | 352,1,444  |
```

with this table my

```
seen_notif_ID column
```

comes from my

```
notif TABLE
```

all user actions are being added to the notif table and a trigger function inside database for AFTER INSERT in notif table also added to seen table.

for the seen_viewers column. if a user clicks his notification with a specific ID of the notification, I will just update this column and add the user_id.

I also have a stored procedure in the database where I can REVERSE CONCAT the seen_viewers column to verify if i already seen that notification ID.

This is the way I get if a user already viewed that particular post/comments/tags/etc .

Is this okay to implement? than making a table for UNNOTIFY?

Answer (score 2):

That is not the way to do it at all. Read some tutorials on database normalization. If you want to track who saw what, DO NOT keep a comma-seperated list of their ids: make a seperate table where each id is a seperate row. This is basic database design. Research one-to-many and many-to-many relationships to see how it is done. Then you will not be wasting time running some 'reverse-concat' function.